# Home page is not loading correctly in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is not loading correctly. Whenever I click on my website address, it is showing the latest post(“Mindblown: a blog about philosophy.” post) which it’s not suppose to be. I want it is showing the home page when people click on my site.

Can anyone help please? Thanks a lot.

I cleared the cache, I tried to adjust the Static page, I also reached out the hosting company, nobody can fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have a static home page template in the theme to display the static home page, like a `front-page.php` file? Recommend reviewing the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more info